# How to set column level permissions for specific users on a Postgres Database already in production without using views?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have users on my postgres database which has select permissions on certain table. Now, I have to hide them few columns which they shouldn't see. When they do

```
select * from "sometable";
```

I want them to see only those columns which i have grant them access them.

I can't create a new views which only the columns that i want them to see.

I have found two options one is feasable other is not.

1. setting column level permissions for users. But have to revoke existing select grant for the user.
2. encryption while inserting data. (But the data is already inserted)

Comment: Do you have a question? You say you find your one option feasible and the other not.

Comment: I need a better way I dont think i solutions i find to be applicable for my particular use case.

Comment: So you want a solution that (a) doesn't involve changing any permissions on the database (b) doesn't use a view and (c) doesn't involve messing with the data? Do you have any sort of idea what *would* be acceptable to you?

Comment: (a) Is Acceptable to me.

Comment: What is the actual question? You know you have to set the permissions, using GRANT and/or REVOKE, you already found that part. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html